# How do I remove a Read-only file system from a usb drive

Tags: filesystems, mount, usb-drive

During an ill-fated attempt to get tinycore linux to boot from a USB drive I managed to create a bunch of files that I now cannot remove.

```
fortino@rebel:/media/working/boot/isolinux$ rm *.*
rm: cannot remove `boot.cat': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove `boot.msg': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove `isolinux.bin': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove `isolinux.cfg': Read-only file system
```

I tried giving myself w and x permission for the files but that didn't appear to work.

What is the best way to clean these files off of this USB drive?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try just wiping out the filesystem via format?

Comment: @ennuikiller - that is what I ultimately had to do.  I was trying to see if there was a more subtle or elegant way of doing it in an effort to better understand what was going on.  In the end that was all that worked though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try to umount and mount it again as read-write.

If this doesn't work for you, create a new filesystem and/or partition table, 
and for that you can use `fdisk` and `mkfs.ext4` or `mkfs.vfat`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  Mounting as rw alone doesn't work - it looks like I may have to go with your second suggestion to just remake the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Did you put an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem on the drive? If so, it can automatically become mounted read-only if there are input/output errors. This comes from the `remount-ro` mount option (however, I think this option doesn't exist for (v)fat, which is usually used on boot media). Check in your kernel logs (typically `/var/log/kern.log`) for errors concerning `/dev/sdb` (or whatever `/dev/*` is that USB drive).

You can try `mount -o remount,rw /mount/point` to access the drive as read-write again, or simply unmount and remount. However, note that if this is the cause of the read-only mount, then the system did it because there was an error, to stop the situation from becoming worse, so there's a small chance the filesystem might not be salvageable anymore. Also, if the error was due to a hardware defect, you should replace the hardware, of course.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  It appeared to remount as rw but it still didn't allow me to remove it...  even with rm -f as root.

Comment: @Kenny - When the say read-only they really mean it eh?

Comment: @boehj - seriously! I am glad I didn't have anything else on that USB so I could just go with the nuclear option.

Answer (score 0):

How about becoming root and doing:

`# rm -f *`

in the proper directory of course.

**EDIT**

It just occurred to me that some flash drives have a physical 'ro' switch. I wonder if that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I think I intentionally purged the idea of running rm -f as root from my brain for my own good but unfortunately it didn't work it still gives me the Read-only file system error